# Hello guys. I have a scenario in which i have to control (basically send messages to) a master node from the internet

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The machine has apache2 and ROS Master. I have also built a Wordpress site on the same machine. What i want to do is to access that wordpress site from the internet (i will buy a router) and use it to send messages to and receive from the ROS Master. Any ideas ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228984/hello-guys.-i-have-a-scenario-in-which-i-have-to-control-(basically-send-messages-to)-a-master-node-from-the-internet/) by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2016-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at [rosbridge_suite](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) and [roslibjs](http://wiki.ros.org/roslibjs).

Keep in mind that having your ROS master or rosbridge server available on the internet means that anyone can access it, unless you explicitly add access controls.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on 2016-03-14**:
Thanks for the quick reply. I will look into it and this is only for a proof of concept. I will be developing more on that later.

**Comment by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on 2016-03-14**:
Thanks a lot bro . I did it. You the man.

**Comment by [Pedrucius](https://answers.ros.org/users/26821/pedrucius/) on 2016-05-17**:
Hello, nishthapa! I have this same issue... How did you made the connection between the 2 nodes? Can you share your code, or part of it? If you prefer, we can talk by e-mail, or facebook chat or whatever...
Thanks!

**Comment by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on 2016-05-25**:
Predrucius, if you mean the internet (a webpage), and the Master node then you will have to keep your master node under a port forwarded router having a public IP. And of course you will have to code the webpage (with JavaScript) yourself. If you want more help, mail me.

**Comment by [Pedrucius](https://answers.ros.org/users/26821/pedrucius/) on 2016-06-18**:
Thanks man! My router had a problem, but now it's solved. Just a simple port forwarding did the trick.

**Comment by [nishthapa](https://answers.ros.org/users/25875/nishthapa/) on 2016-06-18**:
Glad I could be of help.